# how to display component in lightning to all pages like feedback component please see the attachment

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

Here is the example I need the same way to hide and show lightning component to all pages IS this is possible. I already created a feedback component but I don't know how display component in lightning-like hide and show to all pages
[image: Here is the example I need the same way to hide and show lightning component to all pages IS this is possible. I already created a feedback component but I don't know how display component in lightning-like hide and show to all pages]

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Utility Bar' to display above component to all pages. Please check this link : https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/09/10/unlocking-the-lightning-experience-utility-bar/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Utility Bar to achieve the above functionality or if you want a case form to display across the pages, then Salesforce offers Live Agent functionality that can be customized as per requirement and you can the use the live agent snippet to drop across the pages.
This will offer you standard case creation and other standard functionalities.
Refer to the below link to see the demo of Live agent and then you can find trailhead to implement it easily:
https://www.salesforce.com/in/products/service-cloud/features/live-agent/